# Application Jar in WAS_HOME/lib/ext directory throws 'Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger does not implement Log'

Tags: websphere, classloader, apache-commons-logging

When I deploy an application jar which is a custom user registry implementation to $WAS_HOME/lib/ext directory, I am getting the following error -

```
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger does not implement Log
```

nested inside this exception stack -

```
com.ibm.ws.wim.adapter.urbridge.URBridge search 
                                 com.ibm.websphere.wim.exception.WIMApplicationException: CWWIM4506E  Virtual member manager failed to search the entity: 'org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger does not implement Log'.
    at com.ibm.ws.wim.adapter.urbridge.URBridge.search(URBridge.java:652)
    at com.ibm.ws.wim.ProfileManager.searchRepository(ProfileManager.java:5297)
    at com.ibm.ws.wim.ProfileManager.searchImpl(ProfileManager.java:1211)
    at com.ibm.ws.wim.ProfileManager.genericProfileManagerMethod(ProfileManager.java:356)
    at com.ibm.ws.wim.ProfileManager.search(ProfileManager.java:448)
    at com.ibm.websphere.wim.ServiceProvider.search(ServiceProvider.java:544)
    at com.ibm.websphere.wim.client.LocalServiceProvider.search(LocalServiceProvider.java:393)
    at com.filenet.engine.security.VMMProviderVMMImpl$VMMProviderPrivilegedExceptionAction.run(VMMProviderVMMImpl.java:61)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5474)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5600)
    at com.filenet.engine.security.VMMProviderVMMImpl.execSearch(VMMProviderVMMImpl.java:1182)
    at com.filenet.engine.security.VMMProviderVMMImpl.getUserByShortNameOrMail_VMM(VMMProviderVMMImpl.java:552)
    at com.filenet.engine.security.VMMProviderVMMImpl.getUserByShortName_VMM(VMMProviderVMMImpl.java:518)
    at com.filenet.engine.security.VMMProviderVMMImpl.getUserByShortName(VMMProviderVMMImpl.java:180)
    at com.filenet.engine.security.VMMProvider.getUserByShortName(VMMProvider.java:113)
    at com.filenet.engine.security.DirectoryServiceDriver.sspGetUserByName(DirectoryServiceDriver.java:1177)
    at com.filenet.engine.security.DirectoryServiceDriver.getToken(DirectoryServiceDriver.java:712)
    at com.filenet.engine.security.SecurityProvider._getSecurityToken(SecurityProvider.java:564)
    at com.filenet.engine.security.SecurityProvider.getSecurityToken(SecurityProvider.java:477)
    at com.filenet.engine.security.SecurityProvider.getSecurityToken(SecurityProvider.java:457)
    at com.filenet.engine.context.SecurityContext.getToken(SecurityContext.java:193)
    at com.filenet.engine.context.SecurityContext.isSidPresent(SecurityContext.java:224)
    at com.filenet.engine.security.SecurityDescriptor.getEffectiveAccess(SecurityDescriptor.java:472)
    at com.filenet.engine.security.AccessManager.getEffectiveAccess(AccessManager.java:437)
    at com.filenet.engine.retrieve.IndependentClassRetriever.postLoadSecurity(IndependentClassRetriever.java:1414)
    at com.filenet.engine.retrieve.RetrieverClassBase.loadNonScalarProperties(RetrieverClassBase.java:632)
    at com.filenet.engine.retrieve.IndependentClassRetriever.loadNonScalarProperties(IndependentClassRetriever.java:1388)
    at com.filenet.engine.retrieve.IndependentClassRetriever.loadObject(IndependentClassRetriever.java:1174)
    at com.filenet.engine.retrieve.IndependentClassRetriever.getObjectEnumeration(IndependentClassRetriever.java:1294)
    at com.filenet.engine.retrieve.StorageAreaRetriever.getObjectEnumeration(StorageAreaRetriever.java:86)
    at com.filenet.engine.retrieve.IndependentClassRetriever.getObject(IndependentClassRetriever.java:636)
    at com.filenet.engine.retrieve.IndependentClassRetriever.getObject(IndependentClassRetriever.java:357)
    at com.filenet.engine.jca.impl.RequestBrokerImpl.getObjects(RequestBrokerImpl.java:761)
    at com.filenet.engine.context.ServerSession.getObjects(ServerSession.java:165)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.Session.callGetObjects(Session.java:92)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.Session.executeGetObject(Session.java:297)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.Session.getProperty(Session.java:420)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.IndependentObjectImpl.fetchProperty(IndependentObjectImpl.java:119)
    at com.filenet.apiimpl.core.IndependentObjectImpl.fetchProperty(IndependentObjectImpl.java:102)
    at com.filenet.engine.content.StorageAreaCache.rebuildStorageAreaData(StorageAreaCache.java:216)
    at com.filenet.engine.content.StorageAreaCache.getStorageAreaCacheForObjectStore(StorageAreaCache.java:127)
    at com.filenet.engine.content.ContentStorage.getContentAreaList(ContentStorage.java:735)
    at com.filenet.engine.queueitem.StagingCleanup.isStagingCleanupComplete(StagingCleanup.java:96)
    at com.filenet.engine.queueitem.ContentQueueDispatcher.unitOfWork(ContentQueueDispatcher.java:974)
    at com.filenet.engine.tasks.ScheduledBackgroundTask.execute(ScheduledBackgroundTask.java:270)
    at com.filenet.engine.tasks.BackgroundTask.safeExecute(BackgroundTask.java:248)
    at com.filenet.engine.tasks.ScheduledObjectStoreTask.safeExecute(ScheduledObjectStoreTask.java:51)
    at com.filenet.engine.tasks.BackgroundTask$BackgroundTaskPriviledgedExceptionAction.run(BackgroundTask.java:1036)
    at com.filenet.engine.context.CallState.doAsSystem(CallState.java:417)
    at com.filenet.engine.tasks.BackgroundTask.run(BackgroundTask.java:204)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:906)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:929)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:773)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger does not implement Log
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:532)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:272)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:246)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:395)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.<init>(AbstractHttpClient.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:178)
    at com.cst.bpm.CustomDBRegistryImpl.getJSONFromUrl(CustomDBRegistryImpl.java:130)
    at com.cst.bpm.CustomDBRegistryImpl.getUsers(CustomDBRegistryImpl.java:365)
    at com.ibm.ws.wim.adapter.urbridge.URBridge.search(URBridge.java:620)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger does not implement Log
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:416)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:525)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger does not implement Log
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:412)
    ... 61 more
```

The directory $WAS_HOME/lib/ext is listed on the ws.ext.dir variable confirmed from the setupCmdLine.sh file.

**I have not placed the commons-logging-jar in this directory $WAS_HOME/lib/ext as Websphere already provides one out of the box in the plugins or runtime directory.**

My WAS server has the following classloading settings - 

**Access to internal server classes - Allow** 

**Classloader Policy - Multiple**

 **Classloading Module - Classes loaded with parent class loader first**.


So looking to see if anyone has run into this issue and what could be a possible fix?

Comment: I'd suggest adding `-verbose:class` to the generic JVM arguments so you can see where the Jdk14Logger and Log classes are being loaded from.

Comment: try adding a commons-logging.properties file in your classpath

Comment: @SampadaWagde Why would that help?  Can you expand on your thoughts?

Comment: @BrettKail - Here is the output -                                                        `class load: org.apache.commons.logging.Log from: file:/local/apps/BPM85PC/plugins/com.ibm.ws.prereq.commons-logging.jar`

`class load: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger from: file:/local/apps/BPM85PC/plugins/com.ibm.ws.prereq.commons-logging.jar`


`class load: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory from: file:/local/apps/BPM85PC/plugins/com.ibm.ws.prereq.commons-logging.jar`

Comment: @Brett - IBM recommends specifying the extension jar to be specified using ws.ext.dir custom property as opposed to putting the jar in the /$WAS_HOME/lib/ext directory. I am going to try that next

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference since WAS_HOME/lib/ext is just implicitly added to the ws.ext.dirs anyway.  If that's the only entry for org.apache.commons.logging.Log in the -verbose:class output, then I'm stumped.

Comment: @BrettKail - Sorry I overlooked another entry for Log class - `class load: org.apache.commons.logging.Log from: file:/local/apps/BPM85PC/plugins/org.apache.axis2.jar`. Similarly I see another entry for JDK14Logger - `class load: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger from: file:/local/apps/BPM85PC/plugins/org.apache.axis2.jar`. So we have two jars with exactly same classes.

Comment: What are the values of `DefaultHttpClient.class.getProtectionDomain().getLocation()`, `LogFactory.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` and `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` if you print them just before calling `new DefaultHttpClient`?  I suspect there is some conflict between the commons-logging libraries packaged in WebSphere Application Server, and you might need to open a PMR.  It's possible that this scenario simply isn't supported.

Comment: the error could also be because commons-logging is kept at multiple places. check your EAR libraries and WEB-INF/lib . And any other runtime libraries you might be using.